# ggplot2 boxplot with labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I have struggled all day to produce some boxplots using ggplot2. I've finally got the graphic I want but now all I would like to do is add labels to the whiskers and median line to show the actual values. I'd also like to add the count above each plot.

Using the `mpg` data.frame, I've written this code which produces what I want:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(0), hwy, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
geom_boxplot (stat= "boxplot") + 
scale_fill_manual(name="number of cylinders",
                  values=c("0xA6CEE3","0xDFC27D", "0xA6611A", "0x018571" ),
                  breaks=c("4", "5", "6", "8"),
                  labels=c("4", "5", "6", "8")) +
labs(title="fuel efficiency by cylinder", x="", y="highway") +
facet_wrap(~cyl, scale="free_y")
```

OK maybe not so pretty but its all there. Now just to add the labels for each of the quartiles, median and the count of each number of cars per plot (preferably above the plot somewhere). I've searched high and low for an easy explanation for this and can't seem to find one. I understand that I may have to plot some summary data from another data frame against this plot but no idea where to start with this...

If anyone has any tips I'd be glad to hear em!

Answer (score 0):

Revival? :-)

Two steps: derive and condition the statistics, including "where" (`x`, `y`) and text-like things (label, hjust). Then plot (just add a single `geom_text`).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mpgsumm <- mpg %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), q25 = quantile(hwy, 0.25), q50 = median(hwy), q75 = quantile(hwy, 0.75)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(
    lbl = if_else(name == "n", sprintf("n = %.02f", value), sprintf("%.02f", value)),
    value = if_else(name == "n", value[name == "q50"], value),
    x = if_else(name == "n", -Inf, Inf),
    hjust = if_else(name == "n", -0.2, 1.2)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
mpgsumm
# # A tibble: 16 × 6
#    cyl   name  value lbl           x hjust
#    <fct> <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 4     n      29   n = 81.00  -Inf  -0.2
#  2 4     q25    26   26.00       Inf   1.2
#  3 4     q50    29   29.00       Inf   1.2
#  4 4     q75    31   31.00       Inf   1.2
#  5 5     n      29   n = 4.00   -Inf  -0.2
#  6 5     q25    28.8 28.75       Inf   1.2
#  7 5     q50    29   29.00       Inf   1.2
#  8 5     q75    29   29.00       Inf   1.2
#  9 6     n      24   n = 79.00  -Inf  -0.2
# 10 6     q25    19   19.00       Inf   1.2
# 11 6     q50    24   24.00       Inf   1.2
# 12 6     q75    26   26.00       Inf   1.2
# 13 8     n      17   n = 70.00  -Inf  -0.2
# 14 8     q25    16   16.00       Inf   1.2
# 15 8     q50    17   17.00       Inf   1.2
# 16 8     q75    19   19.00       Inf   1.2

ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(0), hwy, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
  geom_boxplot(stat= "boxplot") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="number of cylinders",
                    values=c("0xA6CEE3","0xDFC27D", "0xA6611A", "0x018571" ),
                    breaks=c("4", "5", "6", "8"),
                    labels=c("4", "5", "6", "8")) +
  labs(title="fuel efficiency by cylinder", x="", y="highway") +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, scale="free_y") +
  # the only change to the plot code
  geom_text(data = mpgsumm, aes(x = x, y = value, label = lbl, hjust = hjust))
```

[image: ggplot boxplot with labels]

Still not that pretty, and the labels won't necessarily scale well, but ... frankly, I'm assuming you've since moved on :-)